# Is there a way to set the maximum pool size for a client in Reqwest?

Tags: rust, reqwest

All I've found is that [`ClientBuilder`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.2/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html) has an option for setting the maximum idle connections per host, but this doesn't seem to give an overall limit to the number of connections available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Reqwest works on top of Tokio. You can [configure](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.11/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html) `tokio::Runtime`'s thread count for the whole application.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to configure `tokio::Runtime` to use a separate thread pool for a particular library. Per-library configuration doesn't look possible from my point of view.

Comment: I don't think there's any relationship between the tokio Runtime thread count and the Reqwest connection pool.